How can start the job in the printer's queue
List all jobs in my printer:
lpq -a
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
1st     debian  20      2482850685dzfp_2433200000024816 132096 bytes

How can start the job in the printer's queue then?

You have to have a printer configured to take requests from the queue and print them.
Depending on which printer, and how the printer is connected, setting up a printer is trivial to difficult, but try the easy way first.
Access the CUPS (Common Unix Printing Sysyem) GUI by pointing your browser  to http://localhost:631.
You can detect, add, and manage printers from the Admin tab, and deal with individual printers from the Printers tab. You can set the system default printer.
From the command line,
lpstat -t
will show the total state of the printing system.
